# Pull All subscriber profile attributes using query

Tags: marketing-cloud, subscriber

I would like to pull the Profile attribute from all subscribers (First Name, Last Name) and add it in Data Extension.
I tried querying _EnterpriseAttribute, however, it works only with Enterprise 2.0 account. My SFMC instance has a corporate edition. Currently using _subscribers data view, I'm only able to pull
Email Address and Subscriber Key.
Is there any other way to pull profile attributes?

Comment: Edition != Account type. YOu can have a Corporate edition on an ENT 2.0 account type. The _EA dataview exists only at the top level. where you querying this there?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should use `_Subscribers` and `_EnterpriseAttribute` Data Views together and run the query from the parent Business Unit:

```
SELECT
sub.SubscriberKey,
sub.EmailAddress,
ea.[First Name],
ea.[Last Name] 
FROM _Subscribers sub
LEFT JOIN _EnterpriseAttribute ea on sub.SubscriberID = ea._SubscriberID
```

If that really does not return any results in your case, you can always try to:

1. Use [Tracking Data Extract Activity](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=sf.mc_as_attributes.htm&type=5) in the Automation Studio where you would choose to extract attributes with all subscribers and then import them back to SFMC from SFTP;
2. Or open a ticket with SF Support to [ask them to export All Subscriber with attributes](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/282607/extracting-all-contacts-from-marketing-cloud-contact-builder) into Data Extension, which could be then normally queried.

Comment: You can also run from a child business unit but prefix the data views with Ent schema like this Ent._Subscribers  and Ent._EnterpriseAttribute